# MySQL Update query takes 2.4 seconds to execute and MySQL Process always 100% - 140% CPU

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I recently did a update on my `UPDATE` query to access 2 databases before it only used 1 database (it got slower now 2.4 seconds per execute) and I have to run this UPDATE command every minute or so and now mysqld is always at 140% CPU how do I fix this?

```
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY 
users.ips AS i INNER JOIN auth.visits AS v ON i.hwid = v.hwid 
SET i.last_time = NOW(), i.ping_count = i.ping_count + 1, i.botver='1.0' 
WHERE i.hwid = 'abc123' 
AND i.character_name = 'exampletest' AND (i.ip = '1.2.3.4' OR v.botid='lalaland')
```

[image: sql usage]

details from mysql

```
=====================================
210202 16:51:32 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 34 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1586 1_second, 1584 sleeps, 157 10_second, 25 background, 25 flush
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 1561
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 1975, signal count 1838
Mutex spin waits 222042, rounds 284916, OS waits 1698
RW-shared spins 290, rounds 7724, OS waits 221
RW-excl spins 14, rounds 1070, OS waits 33
Spin rounds per wait: 1.28 mutex, 26.63 RW-shared, 76.43 RW-excl
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
1034 OS file reads, 44087 OS file writes, 7304 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 24.73 writes/s, 5.41 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 276671, node heap has 91 buffer(s)
135.70 hash searches/s, 2.32 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 1573704543
Log flushed up to   1573704543
Last checkpoint at  1573093300
Max checkpoint age    7782360
Checkpoint age target 7539162
Modified age          611243
Checkpoint age        611243
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
6308 log i/o's done, 4.82 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 137756672; in additional pool allocated 0
Total memory allocated by read views 560
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
    Adaptive hash index 3708528     (2213368 + 1495160)
    Page hash           139112 (buffer pool 0 only)
    Dictionary cache    680405  (554768 + 125637)
    File system         127168  (82672 + 44496)
    Lock system         400920  (332872 + 68048)
    Recovery system     0   (0 + 0)
Dictionary memory allocated 125637
Buffer pool size        8191
Buffer pool size, bytes 134201344
Free buffers            6788
Database pages          1309
Old database pages      463
Modified db pages       482
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 1018, created 291, written 36950
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 19.44 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 1309, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
4 transactions active inside InnoDB
4 out of 1000 descriptors used
---OLDEST VIEW---
Normal read view
Read view low limit trx n:o 146E607
Read view up limit trx id 146E5F8
Read view low limit trx id 146E607
Read view individually stored trx ids:
Read view trx id 146E606
Read view trx id 146E601
Read view trx id 146E5FC
Read view trx id 146E5F8
-----------------
Main thread process no. 20190, id 139909004732160, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 85, updated 163656, deleted 69, read 1168845590
0.06 inserts/s, 139.91 updates/s, 0.03 deletes/s, 822976.47 reads/s
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 146E624
Purge done for trx's n:o < 146E603 undo n:o < 0
History list length 912
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 3506, OS thread handle 0x7f3f341eb700, query id 47750 blahblah 1.1.2.3 root
#UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY users.ips AS i 
#INNER JOIN auth.visits AS v ON i.hwid = v.hwid 
#SET i.last_time = NOW(), i.ping_count = i.ping_count + 1, i.botver='1.0' 
#WHERE i.hwid = 'blahblahblah' 
#AND i.character_name = 'blahblah' AND (i.ip = '1.1.1.1' OR v.botid='lalaland')

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 146E623, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 25 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 7546, OS thread handle 0x7f3f16b13700, query id 47749 localhost root Sending data
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY users.ips AS i INNER JOIN auth.visits AS v ON i.hwid = v.hwid SET i.last_time = NOW(), i.ping_count = i.ping_count + 1, i.botver='1.0' WHERE i.hwid = 'blablahblah' AND i.character_name = '' AND (i.ip = '1.2.3.4' OR v.botid='lalaland')
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 0 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 775 n bits 216 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `users`.`ips` trx id 146E623 lock_mode X waiting
------------------
---TRANSACTION 146E622, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 26 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 7544, OS thread handle 0x7f3f168c2700, query id 47748 localhost root Sending data
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY users.ips AS i INNER JOIN auth.visits AS v ON i.hwid = v.hwid SET i.last_time = NOW(), i.ping_count = i.ping_count + 1, i.botver='1.0' WHERE i.hwid = 'blablahblah' AND i.character_name = '' AND (i.ip = '1.1.1.1' OR v.botid='Lalaland')
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 0 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 775 n bits 216 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `users`.`ips` trx id 146E622 lock_mode X waiting
------------------
---TRANSACTION 146E621, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 12 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 7542, OS thread handle 0x7f3f3408a700, query id 47747 localhost root Sending data
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY users.ips AS i INNER JOIN auth.visits AS v ON i.hwid = v.hwid SET i.last_time = NOW(), i.ping_count = i.ping_count + 1, i.botver='1.0' WHERE i.hwid = 'blahblahblah' AND i.character_name = '' AND (i.ip = '1.2.2.2' OR v.botid='Lalaland')
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 0 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 775 n bits 216 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of table `users`.`ips` trx id 146E621 lock_mode X waiting
------------------
---TRANSACTION 146E620, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
478 lock struct(s), heap size 63928, 66086 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 7543, OS thread handle 0x7f3f16b5d700, query id 47746 localhost root Sending data
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY users.ips AS i INNER JOIN auth.visits AS v ON i.hwid = v.hwid SET i.last_time = NOW(), i.ping_count = i.ping_count + 1, i.botver='1.0' WHERE i.hwid = 'blahblahblah' AND i.character_name = 'blahfound' AND (i.ip = '1.3.4.4' OR v.botid='Lalaland')
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

A) SHOW CREATE TABLE users.ips; and

```
CREATE TABLE `ips` (
  `hwid` longtext,
  `ip` longtext,
  `character_name` longtext,
  `locale` longtext,
  `botver` longtext,
  `reg_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ping_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='TRIAL'
```

B) SHOW CREATE TABLE auth.visits; and

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hwid` longtext,
  `ip` longtext,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `locale` longtext,
  `botver` longtext,
  `botid` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3019528 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='TRIAL'
```

C) SHOW INDEX FROM users.ips;
Nothing is returned
[image: users.ip nothing is returned]

D) SHOW INDEX FROM auth.visits; for analysis, please.

```
"Table" "Non_unique"    "Key_name"  "Seq_in_index"  "Column_name"   "Collation" "Cardinality"   "Sub_part"  "Packed"    "Null"  "Index_type"    "Comment"   "Index_comment"
"visits"    "0" "PRIMARY"   "1" "id"    "A" "84"    \N  \N  ""  "BTREE" ""  ""
```

picture:
[image: pic indexes of visits]

Comment: 1. REMOVE low priority directive. Post text results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE users.ips; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE auth.visits; and C) SHOW INDEX FROM users.ips; and D) SHOW INDEX FROM auth.visits; for analysis, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Ok I updated the post I shared everything you requested of me. I want to say that visits is short lived database it gets cleared every 10 to 15 minutes, but the ip's is a backup that keeps all records for archive purposes. I don't really need that `id` table or AUTO_INCREMENT at all I'll probably remove it.

Comment: `LOW PRIORITY` directive i added to try to fix this issue with or without it same issue.

Comment: Do you have flexibility to use Skype TALK  in English to conserve time?  My Skype ID is wlhauck at aol.com  I will be available one more hour today.

Comment: I dont have a microphone.. but ya i got skype. I'll add you hold-on.

Comment: This URL will help.  https://use-the-index-luke.com/  please be familiar with the content and let's connect tomorrow on Skype for a scheduled 15 minute limit, please. What is your Skype ID?  I do not see your invite, yet.  You have NO indexes for your ips table.  (kills performance).  Have a good evening.

Comment: Sorry my skype is loading very slowly, added you

Comment: Wow adding `id` as PRIMARY KEY with `AUTO_INCREMENT on all tables completely solved the problem.. now it takes 0.0% CPU on even the heaviest loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are no useful indexes.  So, change from `LONGTEXT` to some sensble `VARCHAR` and add these:

```
i: INDEX(hwid, character_name, ip)
v: INDEX(botid, hwid)
v: INDEX(hwid, botid)
```

IP addresses, even with IPv6 are no longer than 39.  Use `CHARACTER SET ascii` where appropriate.

But, then there is a different problem:  `OR` is very hard to optimize between two tables, and made even harder by the counter in the update.  But it is possible.

I'm going to do two things:

- Split the `UPDATE` into two `UPDATEs` to avoid the `OR` and make good use of the new indexes.
- Take care of the nasty case where *both* ip=... *and* botid = ... -- This is to avoid the double-increment created by the two updates.

Thus:

```
UPDATE  users.ips AS i
    INNER JOIN  auth.visits AS v  ON i.hwid = v.hwid
    SET i.last_time = NOW(),
        i.ping_count = i.ping_count + 1, i.botver='1.0'
    WHERE  i.hwid = 'abc123'
      AND  i.character_name = 'exampletest'
      AND  i.ip = '1.2.3.4';

UPDATE  users.ips AS i
    INNER JOIN  auth.visits AS v  ON i.hwid = v.hwid
    SET i.last_time = NOW(),
        i.ping_count = i.ping_count + 1, i.botver='1.0'
    WHERE  i.hwid = 'abc123'
      AND  i.character_name = 'exampletest'
      AND  i.ip != '1.2.3.4'       -- Note
      AND  v.botid='lalaland';     -- Note
```

If you are picky about the time, then fetch `NOW()` into an @variable so you can be sure to use the same time in both queries.

Other notes:

- LOW_PRIORITY applies only to MyISAM.
- Adding the `id` was the right thing to do, but it should not have mattered in the performance; something else was happening.  How many rows in the tables?  Were other queries doing significant work with either of these tables?
- Perhaps the slow performance was when the table that gets cleared was especially full.
- If `visits` is cleared frequently, note that auto_increment has gotten to 3019528.

Comment: For the indexes query I get `SQL ERROR (1061): Duplicate key name 'v'`  when I tried ```ALTER TABLE `visits`
 ADD INDEX `v` (`hwid`, `botid`),
 ADD INDEX `v` (`botid`, `hwid`);
```

Comment: This worked I wonder if it's the same thing ```ALTER TABLE `visits`
 ADD INDEX `v` (`hwid`, `botid`),
 ADD INDEX `v2` (`botid`, `hwid`);```

Comment: My ips table had 65,000 rows yesterday today its 72,000 rows.
My visits table has 2,000 rows which has issues.. because some of the data is inserted as duplicate data..  I need to fix that.

Comment: Maybe this log can help? I ran MySQLTuner and it says I need to add alot of paramaters to my.cnf do I need too? https://pastebin.com/raw/eb8pvKAa  yes it's up to 100% CPU after running 1 day.. again

Comment: The problem with visits table having 2,000 rows was probably due to adding the INDEX's while in a live environment lots of the tables got duplicated over 20 times.. after it cleared the list in 10 minutes it dropped to 100 rows only.. I don't think i need to fix my PHP script.. ya now the CPU dropped again to 0%..

Comment: Do I need `Foreign Keys` or just `Indexes`? I got 2 different Ascii character sets to pick from which one do I need Pic: https://i.imgur.com/pbtOXhA.png  Guess I don't need ascii_bin (binary mode) but instead the general since i am not compressing executable programs here. but just plain-text.

Comment: @SSpoke - Giving two indexes the same name seems like an 'error'.  Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; maybe it silently changed one o the names.  Add a `UNIQUE` index to avoid dups; I think it can be done with something like `ALTER IGNORE TABLE t ADD UNIQUE(...)`.  The tables are "small"; perhaps the 100% cpu came from table scans; my indexes should avoid that in the future.

Comment: @SSpoke - A FK is (1) a constraint (and a dynamic check) plus (2) an index.  The `INDEX` (wither from an FK or explicitly) is what gives speed.  `ascii_bin` is case sensitive, `ascii_general_ci` considers 'a' = 'A'..

Comment: so if I use `ascii_general_ci` it won't save correctly? it semes it still disaplys both cases upper and lowercase. So I don't understand it that well.. but hey it works.. so far a few hours in still at 0% cpu no problems here woo!. Where do I need to add the `ADD UNIQUE` to `id` `(first index)`? seems already pretty much unique. As far I understood from `FK` it's used to link other tables to this table and that's it's only use seems I could use that for hwid and avoid the `INNER JOIN?` probably will slow down the whole thing I guess I don't need it. https://pastebin.com/raw/3zWdr6G7

Comment: Ahh the `ascii_general_ci` only used for string comparisons where both letters are retrieved as the same letter.. `a` or `A` thats about it.

Comment: I can't have a unique hwid or ip address only possibly botid can be unique but then again the same botid can be used again if ip or hwid is different. Blah it's not even that important the dups came in because the database was live and got alot of pending queries while I did the alters on the tables.. doesn't seem to happen anymore even after 5 hours.. it's very accurate.. then again I can't tell since it's purged every 10 minutes

Comment: @SSpoke - if you want hwid = 'abc123' to match 'ABC123' and 'Abc123' (etc), then you need `ascii_general_ci`.  Yes, it is for strings (`VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, etc; not `INT` or `DATE`, etc).

Comment: @SSpoke - A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`.

Comment: @SSpoke - Let's focus on indexing.  FKs only complicate the discussion.  (You can add FKs later after you understand things more.)

Comment: @SSpoke - We should discuss the "purge every 10 minutes".  Why?  Every 10 minutes?  Can thousands of rows get added in 10 minutes?  Etc.

Comment: I purge every 10 minutes the visits, as a ping method anyone not in the visits table in 10 minutes after purge is considered a disconnected user. Also every 10 minutes a update happens to the visits for every user who wants to stay connected, which is done by a PHP page. It's okay man thanks for everything seems to be working fine right now. I get some heavy loads sometimes if PHP cannot return a output in time it will retry infinite amount of times without delay until it gets a result and with 100 users like I have.. this can sometimes ddos my website if mysql is running slower.

Comment: @SSpoke - If "purge" id done via `DELETE FROM tbl` to delete all rows, it would be faster (at least for big tables) to do `TRUNCATE TABLE tbl`.

Comment: I cannot use `TRUNCATE TABLE` it seems because some rows don't need to be purged with others do.. some are like 8 minutes existing others 10 minutes.. `TRUNCATE TABLE` seems to delete all rows cannot use `WHERE` I use `$db->query("DELETE FROM visits WHERE time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)");`

Comment: Hey whats your paypal email? I'll send you a tip for all your help.. 24 hours it's still working stable.

Comment: @SSpoke - paypal at rjweb dot org .

Answer (score 1):

Wow adding `id` column as `PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTO_INCREMENT` on all tables as the first column completely solved the problem.. now it takes 0.0% CPU on even the heaviest loads. Even if it gets to 100.0% CPU still.. it only stays there for a fraction of a second then disappears from the list.

Thanks so much Wilson Hauck